Disable Rider performance inspection warning for a particular method
I've begun using Rider for my Unity project and its displaying performance warnings for methods that are unavoidable such as Debug.Log() and Debug.LogError(). Selecting "Disable performance analysis for method" only clears the warning for a single call site. The Inspection Severity category in Settings seems like it only allows me toggle performance analysis for all methods.
Is there any way to disable these warnings project-wide for specific methods?

You can wrap your method into something new and add ReSharper instruction. E.g. make a log wrapper like this:
public static class BDebug
{
        public static void LogException(Exception e)
        {
            _logException(e);
        }

        // THIS WILL DISABLE PERFORMANCE ANALYS

        // ReSharper disable Unity.PerformanceAnalysis
        private static void _logException(Exception e)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogException(e);
        }
}

Actually. I don't recommend you disabling it. I have seen Unity profiler log samples, and when stack traces are enabled it causes enormous CPU spikes, specially on weak devices (mobile).
ZTE Blade L9:

The code behind:

For comparison. This is bush-made gizmo render, rendering 1k shapes, the same ZTE Blade L9:

The code behind:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Beast.Claw.Common;
using Beast.Claw.Debug;
using Beast.Claw.GameCycle;
using Beast.Claw.Graphic;
using Beast.Claw.Mathematics;
using Cysharp.Threading.Tasks;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Profiling;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

namespace Beast.Claw.Gizmo
{
    public class GizmoRender : Controller, IGizmoManager, IGameCycleListener
    {
        private struct HandleInfo
        {
            public GizmoHandle handle;
            public IController owner;
        }

        private const int MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 128;
        
        private readonly ICameraTransform _camera;
        private readonly IScreen _screen;
        private readonly GizmoConfig _config;

        private RenderTexture _canvas;
        private int2 _canvasSize;
        private List<HandleInfo> _handles;
        private Material _canvasMaterial;
        private Material _shapeMaterial;

        private Texture2D[] _texturePool;
        private NativeArray<ushort> _floatBuffer;

        private CommandBuffer _commandBuffer;

        private int _prevTexturePower;
        private int _prevShapeCount;

        public GizmoRender(
            ICameraTransform camera, 
            IScreen screen,
            GizmoConfig config)
        {
            _camera = camera;
            _screen = screen;
            _config = config;
        }
        
        public void Register(IGameCycleHandle handle)
        {
            handle.ListenConcurrent(ActionID.WARMUP, _warmup);
            handle.ListenBlocking(ActionID.RENDER, _render);
            handle.ListenBlocking(ActionID.DISPOSE, _dispose);
        }
        
        public IGizmoHandle CreateHandle(IController owner)
        {
            owner.ValidateNotNullThrowException(nameof(owner));

            HandleInfo info = new ()
            {
                handle = new GizmoHandle(),
                owner = owner,
            };

            _handles.Add(info);

            return info.handle;
        }
        
        private UniTask _warmup(ConcurrentContext context)
        {
            Texture2DParameters textureData = new()
            {
                createInitialized = false,
                format = TextureFormat.RGBAHalf,
                isLinear = true,
                mipChain = false,
                texture = new PlanarTextureData
                {
                    filterMode = FilterMode.Point,
                    wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp
                }
            };
            
            int maxTexturePower = BMath.CeilToInt(BMath.Log2(MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE));
            _texturePool = new Texture2D[maxTexturePower + 1];
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= maxTexturePower; i++)
            {
                _texturePool[i] = BGraphic.CreateTexture2D(this, textureData.WithSize(1 << i));
            }
            
            _handles = new List<HandleInfo>(64);
            
            _canvasMaterial = BGraphic.CreateMaterial(this, _config.canvasShader);
            _shapeMaterial = BGraphic.CreateMaterial(this, _config.shapeShader);
            _commandBuffer = new CommandBuffer();

            _canvas = _setupCanvas(_screen.Size);
            
            return UniTask.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void _render(BlockingContext context)
        {
            if (!_canvasSize.Equals(_screen.Size))
            {
                BGraphic.Dispose(_canvas);

                _canvas = _setupCanvas(_screen.Size);
            }

            int shapeCount = 0;
            
            Profiler.BeginSample("CreateFloatBuffer");
            for (int i = 0; i < _handles.Count; i++)
            {
                HandleInfo handle = _handles[i];

                if (handle.handle.IsDisposed)
                {
                    _handles.RemoveAtSwapBack(i--);
                    continue;
                }

                int handleShapeCount = handle.handle.shapeCount;
                if (handleShapeCount == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                
                GizmoUtil.EnsureCapacity(ref _floatBuffer, shapeCount + handleShapeCount);
                
                _floatBuffer.Slice(shapeCount * GizmoUtil.FLOAT_PER_SHAPE, handleShapeCount * GizmoUtil.FLOAT_PER_SHAPE)
                    .CopyFrom(handle.handle.buffer.Slice(0, handleShapeCount * GizmoUtil.FLOAT_PER_SHAPE));

                shapeCount += handleShapeCount;
            }
            Profiler.EndSample();

            if (shapeCount == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            int textureSize = BMath.CeilToInt(BMath.Sqrt(_floatBuffer.Length / 4.0f));
            if (textureSize > MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)
            {
                BDebug.LogError(this, $"Too big gizmo buffer: ({textureSize * textureSize})");
                return;
            }

            int texturePower2 = BMath.CeilToInt(BMath.Log2(textureSize));
            Texture2D texture = _texturePool[texturePower2];
                
            Profiler.BeginSample("SetPixelData");
            texture.SetPixelData(_floatBuffer, 0);
            texture.Apply();
            Profiler.EndSample();

            if (_prevTexturePower != texturePower2)
            {
                Profiler.BeginSample("SetShapeMaterialParams #2");
                _shapeMaterial.SetTexture("_DataTexture", texture);
                _shapeMaterial.SetFloat("_DataTextureSize", 1 << texturePower2);
                _prevTexturePower = texturePower2;
                Profiler.EndSample();
            }

            _setupMaterialsRare();
            
            Profiler.BeginSample("SetShapeMaterialParams #1");
            _shapeMaterial.SetFloat2("_RenderCenter", _camera.Position);
            _shapeMaterial.SetFloat("_RenderDistance", _camera.ViewDistance);
            Profiler.EndSample();
            
            Profiler.BeginSample("SetRenderTarget");
            Graphics.SetRenderTarget(_canvas);
            Profiler.EndSample();
            
            GL.Clear(true, true, Color.clear);

            if (_prevShapeCount != shapeCount)
            {
                Profiler.BeginSample("SetCommandBufferParams");
                _commandBuffer.Clear();
                _commandBuffer.SetRenderTarget(_canvas);
                _commandBuffer.DrawMeshInstancedProcedural(_config.quadMesh, 0, _shapeMaterial, 0, shapeCount);
                Profiler.EndSample();
                _prevShapeCount = shapeCount;
            }

            Profiler.BeginSample("ExecuteCommandBuffer");
            BGraphic.ExecuteBuffer(_commandBuffer);
            Profiler.EndSample();

            Graphics.SetRenderTarget(null);
            
            Profiler.BeginSample("DrawCanvas");
            BGraphic.DrawMeshDelayed(new DrawMeshTask
            {
                material = _canvasMaterial,
                matrix = new Float4x4TRS
                {
                    rotation = Quaternion.identity,
                    scale = new float3(_screen.Aspect, 1, 1),
                    translation = new float3(0, 0, RenderOrderZ.Gizmo)
                },
                mesh = _config.quadMesh
            });
            Profiler.EndSample();
        }

        private RenderTexture _setupCanvas(int2 screenSize)
        {
            RenderTexture canvas = BGraphic.CreatePermRenderTexture(this, new RenderTextureData
            {
                format = RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32,
                texture = new PlanarTextureData
                {
                    filterMode = FilterMode.Point,
                    wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp,
                    size = screenSize
                },
                temp = new TempRenderTextureData
                {
                    antiAliasing = 1
                }
            });
            
            _canvasSize = screenSize;
            
            _setupMaterialsRare();

            return canvas;
        }

        private void _setupMaterialsRare()
        {
            Profiler.BeginSample("_setupMaterialsRare");
            
            _shapeMaterial.SetFloat2("_ScreenSize", _canvasSize);
            _canvasMaterial.SetTexture("_Texture", _canvas);

            float rollCos = BMath.Cos(_camera.RotationRad.roll);
            float pitchCos = BMath.Cos(_camera.RotationRad.pitch);
            
            float2x2 rotation = float2x2.Rotate(_camera.RotationRad.roll * -1);
            float2x2 scale = float2x2.Scale(1, pitchCos);
            
            _shapeMaterial.SetFloat2x2("_ViewMatrix0", rotation);
            _shapeMaterial.SetFloat2x2("_ViewMatrix1", scale);
            
            _shapeMaterial.SetFloat("_ProjectionScale", 1f / (rollCos * pitchCos));
            
            Profiler.EndSample();
        }
        
        private void _dispose(BlockingContext context)
        {
            BGraphic.Dispose(_canvas);

            foreach (Texture2D texture in _texturePool)
            {
                BGraphic.Dispose(texture);
            }

            _floatBuffer.Dispose();
            _commandBuffer.Dispose();

            BGraphic.Dispose(_canvasMaterial);
            BGraphic.Dispose(_shapeMaterial);
        }
    }
}

Particularly, I have been googling for this question, because I needed to disable it in the very specific case, where it is allowed:
        // ReSharper disable Unity.PerformanceAnalysis
        public static string ToStringNonAlloc(this int value)
        {
            if (value < 0 && -value <= _negativeBuffer.Length)
            {
                return _negativeBuffer[value * -1 - 1];
            }

            if (value >= 0 && value < _positiveBuffer.Length)
            {
                return _positiveBuffer[ value];
            }

            if (!_allocationReported)
            {
                _allocationReported = true;
                
                Debug.LogError("ToStringNonAlloc() Failed. Not withing range: " + value);
            }
            
            return value.ToString();
        }

Note, that log can be produced only once:

Moreover. You can abuse .Log() to create context-critical markers. For some reason, Rider was not detecting Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll, so added marker:



In File | Settings | Editor | Inspection Settings | Inspection Severity | C#, you can adjust the inspection severity level and trun off the warning messages.


I should have been more specific: I only want these warnings disabled for those specific methods. I still want warnings for all other method calls. I'll update my question with this detail
